# Install Hippo CMS : NullPointerException with essentials webapp

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, hippocms

I followed these instructions ([Hippo CMS installation instructions](http://www.onehippo.org/trails/getting-started/hippo-essentials-getting-started.html)) to install Hippo CMS 7.

I followed :

- Step 1 : run Maven archetype locally
- Step 2 : compile & package locally with Maven
- I did not followed step 3 instruction, as I build the WAR files (cms.war, essentials.war and site.war) on my Windows 8.1 / Oracle JDK 8 / Maven 3.3 locally and transfer generated WAR files on a Debian 7 / Oracle JDK 8 / Tomcat 8 / no Maven server

What I get :

- http://{myserver}:{myport}/cms is working perfectly
- http://{myserver}:{myport}/console is working perfectly
- http://{myserver}:{myport}/site is working perfectly
- http://{myserver}:{myport}/essentials give a HTTP 500 error code (but WAR is correctly deployed and launched)

Stack trace :

```
08-Apr-2015 19:39:55.565 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet REST a généré une exception
 java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:324)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:237)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:239)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:213)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:131)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:266)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:191)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:242)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:165)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:89)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
        ... 30 more
**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.plugin.PluginStore.getAllPlugins(PluginStore.java:125)
        at org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.rest.PluginResource.getModules(PluginResource.java:290)**
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        ... 35 more
```

It seems that "GET /essentials/rest/plugins" web service is the call generating the exception.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described on One Hippo's setup [instructions](http://www.onehippo.org/library/setup/introduction.html), the setup application is intended for use on the local development host only.

This is because it strongly interacts with your project's files. As such, using it on a remote server doesn't make much sense. Once you leave the development host, don't bother deploying the essentials WAR. (Note how the Hippo project distribution does not include the essentials WAR.)